# Separate routing logic from component logic in Angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

I'm trying to learn Angular, and I have a separation-of-concerns problem with routing. In all guides I found, when happens is that you specify the route and parameters in the routing module, but parse them in the component file. For example, in the classic Tour of Heroes example:

```js
// in app-routing.module.ts
{ path: 'hero/:id': component: HeroDetailComponent }

// in hero-detail.component.ts
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private heroService: HeroService,
  private location: Location
) {}

ngOnInit() {
     const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.heroService.getHero(id)
    .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
}
```

But earlier in the tutorial, what you had was that a `Hero` object was used as `Input()`:

```js
@Input() hero: Hero;
```

And you would bind to it:

```html
<hero-detail [hero]='hero'></hero-detail>
```

What I would want is to be able to keep that logic, and instead parse the URL and pass the `Input()`s in the same file as the routing module, and keep the component file as-is. Something like:

```js
// app-routing.module.ts
{
    path: 'hero/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent, inputs: path => ({ hero: getHeroObject(+path.params["id"]) })
}
```

Is there any option in Angular routing to do something like this? If not, can you think of a roundabout-way to separate the logic parts? One thing of which I thought is to create separate components in the routing module for each path, each of them renders the "pure-logic" component, something like:

```js
// app-routing/hero-detail-route.component.ts
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private heroService: HeroService,
  private location: Location
) {}

ngOnInit() {
     const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.heroService.getHero(id)
    .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
}
```

```html
<!--- app-routing/hero-detail-route.component.html -->
<hero-detail [hero]='hero'></hero-detail>
```

But that's just kind of "kicking the problem down the road", isn't it?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways.

**1. Using `resolvers`**

You can attach a resolver in the route like

```
{
    path: 'hero/:id',
    component: HeroDetailComponent,
    resolve: {
        hero: HeroDetailResolver
    }
}
```

`HeroDetailResolver` will contain all the logic to get the hero detail from server. In `component` you catch resolver data.

```
this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
    this.hero = data.hero;
});
```

If you are not familiar with `angular resolvers` they are a handy tool to pre-fetch some server data before `component` loads.

**2. Using `smart parent` and `dumb child` components**

Use a `smart parent component` to fetch all server data and provide them to `dumb child components`. In this case you can make `HeroDetailLayoutComponent` to fetch the hero detail. Then pass it as `@Input()` to `HeroDetailComponent`.

```
// in app-routing.module.ts
{ path: 'hero/:id': component: HeroDetailLayoutComponent }

// in hero-detail-layout.component.ts
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private heroService: HeroService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.heroService.getHero(id).subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
}

// hero-detail-layout.component.html
<hero-detail [hero]='hero'></hero-detail>

// in hero-detail.component.ts
@Input() hero: any[];
```